# Obtain output parameter values from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @var varchar(max),@course varchar(max)
set @var='ABC'
set @Query=''
set @Query='  
select @course=PARAM from TABLE where PARAM='''+@var+''''
print @Query
exec (@Query)
```

Since the above query returns an error as

> Must declare the scalar variable "@course"

The query here is the alternative I am following right now to make that query successful.

```
declare @var varchar(max),@course varchar(max),@Query varchar(max)
Create table #temp(param1 varchar(max))
set @var='ABC'
set @Query=''
set @Query='insert #temp(param1)
select PARAM from TABLE where PARAM='''+@var+''''
print @Query
exec (@Query)
select @course=param1 from #temp
drop table #temp
```

Is there any other better alternative to this other than the solution I have mentioned above?

Comment: As you have seen, i want to assign the value retrieved from "TABLE" based on where condition. Here i used exec (@Query), because, in my requirement, "TABLE"'s Name is dynamic (say 'TABLE_2012','TABLE_2013') and so i should form the query dynamically.

Comment: TABLE_2012 and TABLE_2013 sounds like a terrible design decision. Why not have a single table partitioned or clustered on a year column? Now you don't need dynamic SQL, the performance will be quite similar, and schema management will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well I'm not sure that you actually need to use dynamic SQL here, but I suspect that you dumbed down a more complex example for us. (Tip: you don't need to do that.)

If this is all you're doing, then why not just:

```
SELECT @course = PARAM FROM dbo.Table WHERE PARAM = @var;
```

(Which doesn't even make sense - by definition `@course` and `@var` are either equal or the row doesn't exist.)

If your SQL is actually more complicated, then you need to STOP using `EXEC()` and embrace `sp_executesql`. One of the things this allows is much more flexibility with strongly-typed parameters (including `OUTPUT`). Here is a quick example:

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME;

DECLARE @var VARCHAR(MAX), @course VARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @var = 'ABC', @table_name = N'TABLE_2012';

SET @sql = N'SELECT @course = PARAM FROM ' + @table_name 
  + ' WHERE PARAM = @var;'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@var VARCHAR(MAX),@course VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT',
  @var, @course OUTPUT;

PRINT @course;
```

Comment: In my requirement, "TABLE"'s Name is dynamic (say 'TABLE_2012','TABLE_2013') and so i should go for  dynamic SQL

Comment: Could not have been explained better and more concisely. Thank you, Aaron!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
declare @var varchar(max),@course varchar(max),@paramdef varchar(100)

set @var='ABC'
set @Query=''
set @Query=N'  
select @result=PARAM from TABLE where PARAM='''+@var+''''
set @paramdef=N'@result varhcar(20) OUTPUT'

execute sp_executesql @Query,@paramdef,@result=@course Output

SELECT @course
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare variable on the dynamic query itself

```
declare @var varchar(max)
set @var='ABC'
set @Query=''
set @Query='  
DECLARE @course varchar(max)
select @course=PARAM from TABLE where PARAM='''+@var+'''

SELECT @course
'
print @Query
exec (@Query)

--Reusing variable
    CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
        VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)
    )
    INSERT INTO #temp
    EXEC (@Query)
    SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Comment: And then how do you use the value of `@course` after the `EXEC` has finished? This eliminates the immediate error but it doesn't solve the actual problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have modified my answer, isn't that okay??

Comment: Ok, now you've solved the problem, but it isn't very efficient to create a #temp table to hold a single value...