# Build select statement dynamically and use it to populate a stored procedure variable

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get count of a rows with specific values in a table, and if the count is 0, then add a value in the table. This count is a local variable in stored procedure.

I am building the SQL dynamically and storing SQL statement into a `nvarchar` variable.

Then, using `EXEC` I am running this SQL as follows hoping to populate count variable.

But it's not working.

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @count INT

-- building @qry will result as follows
@qry = SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM aTable WHERE (col1 = @col1 AND ...)


@count = EXEC @qry
IF @count = 0
BEGIN
  -- carry on with adding
END
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? Are you getting a different result than you expected?

Comment: This should help I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968512/assign-result-of-dynamic-sql-to-variable

Comment: Try doing it with `@count` as an `OUT` parameter, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589466/execute-stored-procedure-with-an-output-parameter) may help.

Comment: at `@count = EXEC @qry` it gives me error. Incorrect syntax near '@count'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building the query dynamically, you need `sp_executesql`. Try something like

```
-- building @qry will result as follows
@qry = 'SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM aTable WHERE (col1 = @col1 AND ...)'

EXEC sp_executesql @qry, N'@count INT OUTPUT', @count OUTPUT;
--Do whatever you want with @count...
```

**Source**: Aaron Bertrand's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786335/obtain-output-parameter-values-from-dynamic-sql) and [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) explanation..

Answer (score 1):

In your sql ,why you are execute your query through EXEC because of your required output is already in @count variable so it is not need in your case.
Please refer below syntax.

```
DECLARE @qry Numeric
DECLARE @count INT

-- building @qry will result as follows
SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM aTable WHERE (col1 = @col1 AND ...)

IF @count = 0
BEGIN
  -- carry on with adding
END
```

Comment: but before `if` dynamic sql is not executed. I guess, or does it?

Comment: But it is not need because your count of record available in @count variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think @qry needs to be a string for executing, not the result of the select, like so:

```
DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @count INT;

-- building @qry will result as follows
SET @qry = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aTable WHERE (col1 = @col1 AND ...)';

SET @count = exec @qry;
```