# How should this variable be declared in dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using dynamic SQL to loop through a specific list of databases.  I get an error that the scalar variable @dealerDBName must be declared when trying to open the db. See line:  `USE ['+ QUOTENAME(@dealerDBName) +']`. I tried removing the brackets, plus signs and quote marks but then get an error that @dealerDBName is not a valid db.  How do I correct this?

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max);

SET @sql = N'
    DECLARE @dealerDBName AS varchar(10)

    DECLARE @TodaysDBs AS TABLE(
            [CustID]        varchar(10),
            [OrderNbr]      varchar(20),
            --[CabinetCount]    int,
            [UniqueID]      int IDENTITY(1, 1)
        );

    INSERT INTO
        @TodaysDBs
    SELECT 
        CustID,
        OrderNbr
    FROM
        xxx.yyy.zzz
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, OrderSubmitted)) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))


    DECLARE @lineNbr AS int = 1;

    SET @CountOfOrders = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TodaysDBs)

    WHILE @lineNbr <= @CountOfOrders
    BEGIN
        SET @dealerDBName = (SELECT CustID FROM @TodaysDBs WHERE UniqueID = @lineNbr)
        USE ['+ QUOTENAME(@dealerDBName) +']

        /* do stuff */
        SET @lineNbr = @lineNbr + 1;
    END

    SELECT * FROM @CabinetCountTable'

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '"', '''')
    
    EXEC(@sql)  

END
```

Comment: You only use it in your d-sql yet you try to reference it (concatenate it) in your outer scope! It looks like you're not sure how to use dynamic sql here. Also fyi objects should be declared as `sysname`

Comment: The error I get isn't about the variable `@dealerDBName`, and I get multiple *other* errors: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BG-Xtc6F)

Comment: If you're trying to get variables declared inside dynamic SQL out of it after you've executed the dynamic SQL, [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15786470/61305). In general, this is one of many reasons [most prefer `sp_executesql` over `EXEC()`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).

Comment: I see a couple of issues. (1) I believe you need to move most of your loop logic outside the dynamic SQL, leaving just the `USE` and `/* do stuff */` in the dynamic sql constructed and executed inside the loop. (2) When you use `QUOTENAME()`, you don't need to add your own square brackets. (3) If the intent is that the dynamic SQL cumulatively populates `@CabinetCountTable`, you will need to change that to a temp table `#CabinetCountTable` accessible both outside and inside the dynamic sql. (4) I suggest you look into using a `CURSOR` loop.

Comment: Also think about vastly simplifying by, say, [`sp_ineachdb`](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_ineachdb.sql). (Disclaimer: I wrote [the original version](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server-part-2/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).)

Answer (score 0):

Most of this code does not need to be in dynamic SQL. And the bits that do, instead of using `USE SomeDB` *inside* the SQL, you can just do `EXEC @proc @sql` where `@proc` is `SomeDB.sys.sp_executesql`.

Also

- Don't use a `WHILE` to avoid a `CURSOR`, it isn't any faster.
- You also shouldn't bother using a table variable to avoid a `STATIC` cursor, there is no gain.
- Database and object names should be of `sysname` type, an alias for `nvarchar(128)`
- SQL text should be `nvarchar(max)`.
- Don't do functions on `WHERE` or `JOIN` columns, instead move the functions to the constant side of the comparison.

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(max) = '
-- some SQL here
';

DECLARE @dealerDBName AS sysname;
DECLARE @crsr CURSOR;

SET @crsr = CURSOR STATIC FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT 
    CustID
FROM
    xxx.yyy.zzz
WHERE 
    OrderSubmitted >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
    AND OrderSubmitted >= DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime));

OPEN @crsr;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH @crsr INTO @dealerDBName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK;

    DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000) = @dealerDBName + '.sys.sp_executesql';

    EXEC @proc @sql; --add parameters if necessary, do not inject
END;
```